# Do I need locks anytime I read other classes' fields in a multithread app?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a game server and I am not exactly sure if I need to lock even things like that:

```
 public string Name
        {
            get { return this.pName; }
            protected set
            {
                this.pName = value;
            }
        }
```

then an example from an NPC class:

```
 public virtual void CalculateHitDamage(Player p, int dmg)
        {
            this.pLastAttackerName = p.Name;
....
```

As Player requests are processed usinsg the threadpool, should I make sure that all fields are protected with locks? In this case, the Name field?

Comment: Why not `this.pLastAttacker = p;` ?

Comment: Even you get the up-to-date name with a locking mechanism, the other player (the attacker) can update their name later on. But if you keep a reference to the Player object, you will always have access to their current, up-to-date information.

Comment: For information like points, power, health etc., which should not fall victim to a race condition during concurrent update operations, you can use the `Interlocked` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @OguzOzgul The thing is - if I store the reference to Player in the NPC, then it will be there even if the Player disconnects. And when they reconnect, they will be in another instance but the name is always unique.

Comment: Ok but if a player disconnects and another player connects using the same name, will the attacker be seen as the new player?

Comment: @OguzOzgul That is not possible, names are authorized against passwords ;) Thanks for the Interlocked class, that seems to be what I need!